# Making webpage fit to screen resolution

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have a web page with the following content..

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="lsidebar"> 
  </div>
  <div id="content">
  </div>
  <div id="rsidebar">
  </div>
</div>
```

i need a container to be centered always on the screen.

[image: Webpage layout]

the container width would be the half of the screen.i use margin-left for centering the container.But it is different for different browser.

Another problem:i am adding float:left for lbar,content,rbar.but the rbar is moving to next line like this...
[image]

Here is my css

```
#container
{
        position:absolute;
    width:75%;
    left:15%;



}
#header{width:100%;height:430px;}
#content{position:relative;top:0px;width:60%;}
#rsidebar{border:2px solid black;width:100px;height:200px;float:left;}
#footer{position:relative;top:10px;width:100%;}
```

how to solve this issue...

Comment: Using floating elements, I fear you'll have to use client side scripting to set the width dynamically.

Comment: why not float:right?  is there an over-flow:hidden? is there any padding ?

Comment: when i use float:right,the div moves to right of the conatiner,but it remains in the bottom of the content.i can't use margin-top:-200px like this,bcoz i will not same for all screen resolution.

Comment: i added my css...just check it thnx

Comment: can anyone provide me a css for this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first: give the container a width and

```
margin-left auto; margin-right:auto;
```

do you use a meyerweb reset stylesheet?

Comment: but i want a container exactly to the center of the screen.i have mention that the width of the container is half the width of the page..

Comment: margin-left:auto; and margin-right:auto; center this div if you give it a width
you should add a reset css (meyerweb) so its looks right in every browser and it resets also some values by the browser stylesheets

Comment: remind the boxmodel (if you have a padding of 10px, your width should be 20px less because the padding, and also margin is added to the width so width:500px and padding 10px = real width:520px – Daniel Ruf 0 secs ago

Comment: i set a width of a container to 75% and i'm using left:15%.But it wouldn't be same for all screen resolution.when i replace 15% by margin:auto.the container remains left of the screen.

Comment: dont use left:15%  use margin-left:auto; and margin-right:auto; for horizontal

Comment: yeah..i tried but the container still remains in left of the screen..it is not coming to center of the screen.

Comment: well dont use:        position:absolute;   delete this or it sets left:0px;

Comment: k...now it's working on my window screen.let me check in iMac.

Comment: yeah..it's working..can you tell what margin-left:auto and margin-right:auto do.

Comment: that means that the browser automatically sets the margins

Comment: in this case you wanted it centered, if you dont want it centered, just give it a fix margin-left instead of auto

Comment: Doubt:if i put margin-left:some_value.Is it remains same in all resolution.

Comment: thtas true  but dont use position:absolute or it will be left:0px;

Comment: yeah..now i understand the concept.Anyway thanx for your valuable comment.

Answer (score 4):

> the container width would be the half of the screen.i use margin-left for centering the container.

Sorry?

If the container is half of the screen, you'll have a `width:50%`. If you want to center it, you'll have `margin:0 auto;`.

There are only two appropriate techniques to center items on a page: `text-align:center;` for content, `margin:0 auto;` for blocks. You may be tempted to do something like `margin-left:25%;width:50%;`, but it will probably not give the expected results in all browsers and cause too many problems, so try to stick with the techniques that everybody uses for years, unless you can prove that your technique is much better.

> Another problem:i am adding float:left for lbar,content,rbar.but the rbar is moving to next line

Probably **the outer width of three panels is bigger than the width of the container**. Note that we're talking about the outer width, not the `width` itself. For example if the container element is 1067 pixels width and contains two panels of 200 pixels and one panel of 600 pixels, with 50 pixels margin between, the actual width of three panels will be 200×2 + 600 = 1000, but the outer width will be 1000 + 50×2 = 1100, i.e. greater than 1067 pixels.

To avoid problems with the widths of the panels, especially in the case where your container has a variable width depending on the size of the window, **you can float-left the left panel, float-right the right one and keep the central panel to fill the remaining space**. This may not always be possible depending on your layout and design. If this is a case, it would be great to see the actual source code in your question to be able to give a more specific answer.

---

Seing your source code, I don't understand why are you using `position:absolute` and `position:relative` for nearly every element. What's the point?

**1. Aligning the container**

To align the container, you have to specify not only the width, but also the margins.

```
div#container{margin:0 auto;width:50%;}
```

**2. Float-lefting the panels**

Now that you have your container filling the half of the space and centered, let's position the panels.

Your right panel has a width of 100 pixels. I suppose that your left panel has the same width.

```
div#lbar,
div#rbar{width:100px;}
```

Let's float-left and float-right them:

```
div#lbar,
div#rbar{width:100px;float:left;} /* Apply this style to both side panels */
div#rbar{float:right;} /* Override the float:left of the preceding line */
```

Now, we want the central panel to avoid filling the space already filled by two other panels:

```
div#content{margin:0 100px;}
```

That's pretty all you need to do.

---

I may also suggest you to read some books about HTML/CSS. Looking at your code, I might suppose that you're not very familiar with it, and that some reading may improve both your understanding of both languages and your skills.

Comment: here i'm setting container width to 76% and left:15%.so that my container is in the center of the screen.Next pblm:when i reduce the size of the rsidebar to 50px.the pblm remains same

Answer (score 0):

The combined width of you lbar + content + rbar + margins+ padding is probably more than the space in your container; therefore your rbar moves to the bottom.

ALso use the container solution of Daniel

Comment: remind the boxmodel (if you have a padding of 10px, your width should be 20px less because the padding, and also margin is added to the width so width:500px and padding 10px = real width:520px

Comment: no i'm not using any padding..for the container or lsidebar or content or rsidebar

Comment: or margin? or do you use a border?

Comment: i'm using margin only for the inner content.(ie)inside the header div,content div for other elements

Answer (score 0):

You can use `margin: auto` to center container horizontally.  About sidebars you probably want `lbar`, `rbar`, `content` in markup and `float: left`, `float: right` for `lbar` and `rbar` respectively.  Remember to put `clear: both` on footer just in case.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use HTML5 or something like http://lessframework.com to specify conditions for different screen sizes.

Comment: when i check it 2560x1440(iMac).the website totally collapses